# Does JAVA have API to access the login history from sql server management studio?

Tags: java

I want to get the historic server URL that users log into sql server from sql server management studio. Is there JAVA API to implement it? The .NET has it.

Comment: I don't see how an end user tool could be accessed from a Java program. Management Studio is a .Net application, I don't think you can connect to that using a Java program. And I don't understand what the login history for management studio should be - after all you log in to the *server* not to the client application.

Comment: The login history is like the url of the server such as localhost,1433 that the user connected to. I agree with you. I may have to call .dll with JAVA to get such information.